# Why current_setting() value is undefined within the exception block

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

After setting the configuration parameter with `set_config()` I can read it with `current_setting()`. But if exception ocured and I try to read value within the exception block it is undefined.

```
do $$declare
    l_ctx_prm text := 'some_value'; 
    l_dummy numeric;
begin
    raise notice 'test before set_config: [utl_log.test_ctx=%]', current_setting('utl_log.test_ctx', true);  
    perform set_config('utl_log.test_ctx', l_ctx_prm, false);
    raise notice 'test after set_config: [utl_log.test_ctx=%]', current_setting('utl_log.test_ctx', true);  
    l_dummy := 1/0; -- raise exception 
exception when others then
    raise notice 'test in exception block: [utl_log.test_ctx=%]', current_setting('utl_log.test_ctx', true);  
end$$;
```

The result is

```
test before set_config: [utl_log.test_ctx=<NULL>]
test after set_config: [utl_log.test_ctx=some_value]
test in exception block: [utl_log.test_ctx=]
```

Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING):

> When an error is caught by an EXCEPTION clause, the local variables of the PL/pgSQL function remain as they were when the error occurred, but all changes to persistent database state within the block are rolled back.

The call to `set_config` is an attempt to change persistent state, so the effects are rolled back prior to entering the exception block.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't expect session variables to fall under the concept of "persistent database state". Maybe that third parameter in `set_config` is what caused the confusion. Based on the description, it seems that setting it to `false` means that the values persist after the transaction is completed/terminated.  

Does PostgreSQL have any alternative ways to store global variables? For example, Oracle has DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT or package variables. I need them for custom logging functions.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have any variables. What you call "variable" is really a placeholder parameter (part of the state of the database), hence the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to put the block with the exception handler right where the potential error can happen, so that your parameter setting isn't rolled back:

```
BEGIN
    PERFORM set_config('utl_log.test_ctx', l_ctx_prm, false);
    BEGIN
        l_dummy := 1/0; -- raise exception 
    EXCEPTION WHEN division_by_zero THEN
        /* handle the exception */
    END;  
END;
```

Basically, you should follow two rules for good programming

- don't handle errors with a lazy catch-it-all exception handler around your whole code
- catch specific exceptions that you expect to avoid masking unexpected errors

Comment: Thank you for the comment regarding the use of `set_config` outside the main execution block. Typically, more complex/sensitive code is encapsulated within internal functions with their own error-handling logic. Therefore, rolling back the parameter value to the one that existed before executing the internal function/block is sufficient for my exception-handler use case (initially, I thought it was completely discarded).

Comment: Regarding the potential error masking in the `when others then` section, I understand that. My example was minimized for the `set_config` test. Typically, I have separate handlers for known errors, while in the general `when others then` section, there's usually code for logging error context (such as error_stack, local variables/parameters), followed by error propagation/reraise.

Comment: With my comment about good coding style I didn't want to imply that you don't know that. It is good that you simplified the example for the question.